# R3 Insights into industrial scale claims

Tags: 3d-design

Does anybody know anyone from the R3 team or have any insights  into their scalability and reliability claims?

The format and potential cost savings are appealing...

We are looking for an industrial scale 3D printing solution for the connectors that make up our TWIND Power Exoblades and R3 looks like a cool startup, on their web page at least

https://r3printing.com/

https://discordapp.com/channels/532618939486699520/532622198133882880

https://discord.gg/JFxAXzd

r2

Comment: They make some interesting performance claims, with 0 hard info to back them up. One wonders who they're using as the reference for "competition".

Comment: Agreed, I am looking elsewhere but keeping an eye on them as well beyond the website spin..